# Translate bash script from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to Linux and am trying to find the equivalent of this from Windows

```
@echo off
if ".%1" == "." goto TellSyntax
set
PRE_CLASSPATH=%MW_HOME%\oracle_common\modules\javax.persistence_2.1.jar;%MW_HOME%\wlserver\modules\com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
goto End
:TellSyntax
echo setJPA21SupportPatch %MW_HOME%\wlserver\modules
:End
echo PRE_CLASSPATH=%PRE_CLASSPATH%
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Good start is checking [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) site.

Comment: It might be helpful not just to provide the batch script and tell us to translate it, but to describe what are you doing here, for which products the jars are needed and tell us a bit more about the dependencies. Otherwise someone would just suggest how to set things in a general way.

Comment: you're right, as I say I am newbie in computing but in general , this bash is to configure weblogic server with JPA 2.1, the bash configure persistence on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo setJPA21SupportPatch $MW_HOME/wlserver/modules
  else
    export PRE_CLASSPATH=$MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/javax.persistence_2.1.jar:$MW_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
fi

echo PRE_CLASSPATH=$PRE_CLASSPATH
```